# Differentiability of functions of several variables.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've just read the proof of a theorem which states that if a function of several variables(two in this case) has partial derivatives in some neighborhood of a point (x,y) and these derivatives are continuous at (x,y) then the function is differentiable at that point. The proof uses the mean value theorem and ,analytically, I understand the proof but I can't feel why it is necessary to have these derivatives in a neighborhood not just in a point. Can someone experienced share his intuitive view on this question and show me some intuitive reasons for this being necessary?

Comment: This is by no means an answer, just how I look at it. Although you say that a function can be continuous AT a point, it intuitively means that there are no jumps Around that point. So continuity at a point also tells you a bit about the function around that point.

Comment: The best way to understand this sort of thing is to see a counterexample. Typically, for this sort of fundamental phenomenon, Wikipedia has good examples and counterexamples. In the present case, looking up "differentiability" yields [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) with examples that throw some light on your question.

Answer (score 2):

Limits are far more subtle when you have more than $1$ variable. Consider the standard counterexample function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\,, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0\,, & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}\,.$$
This function is not continuous at the origin, but both its partial derivatives are $0$ at the origin. Thus, if we were to have a tangent plane, it would be horizontal. On the other hand, along the line $y=(\tan\theta) x$, the function has *value* $\frac12\sin 2\theta$ everywhere except the origin. So existence of partials doesn't even give you continuity.

A continuous variant of this is given by
$$g(x,y) =  \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\,, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0\,, & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}\,.$$
The tangent plane would still be horizontal, if it existed, but the function now has *directional derivative* $\frac12\sin2\theta$ in direction $\theta$. Thus, our alleged tangent plane doesn't contain tangent lines to the surface other than in the coordinate directions.

What you should try to find is a function *all* of whose directional derivatives at the origin are $0$ but which is nevertheless not differentiable (e.g., not continuous).

Comment: Sir , just a quick follow-up on this. The proof of the theorem that OP stated essentially uses the lagrange MVT for partial derivatives.I understand the proof but i just become a little hesistant on applying LMVT on partial derivatives. What is the essence of lagrange  MVT and where in all it comes into picture ?

Comment: @llecxe There's no problem applying MVT in one variable at a time. The problem comes in trying to deduce something about the function as a whole. A function can be continuous along every line through a point without being continuous at the point!

Comment: 'A function can be continuous along every line through a point without being continuous at the point!' -this is such a beautiful way of looking. thanks sir

Comment: @llecxe It's way worse than that. A function can be continuous on every curve $|y|=c|x|^n$ ($c\ge 0$, $n\in\Bbb N$) and still not be continuous at the origin.

Comment: Sir, just to get into some nit-picking here. When we apply LMVT in case of partial derivatives say $f_x$, we essentially assume that $y$ is kept constant for a two-variable function $f(x,y)$.I just don't get the idea, maybe $F(x,y)$ be an implicit function . Can we still apply LMVT ?

Comment: @llecxe What is an implicit function $F(x,y)$? I think you've wandered so far in these comments that you should just post a carefully-written question of your own.

Comment: may be you are right